# Outputting a word file using Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-writing

I want to write a function that takes number n as input, then outputs a tab separated word document that looks like 5 rows of:

1 2 3...n n n-1 n-2 ..1

Let me tell you what I have tried already: It is easy to create a vector like this with the integers I want, but if I save a file in an ascii format, in the output the integers come out in a format like " 1.0000000e+00".
Now I googled to find that the output can be formatted using %d and fprintf, but given the row length is part of the input, what would be the most efficient way to achieve it?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you say "word document" do you mean Microsoft Word Document or a plain text file?

Comment: Please clarify if you actually mean Microsoft Word Document or a text file.

Comment: I mean a notepad document, not a MS Word one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
Nrow = 5;
N = 10;
dlmwrite('my_filename.txt', repmat([1:N, N:-1:1], Nrow, 1), 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', '%d');
```

Comment: If it really is just a plain text file I'd recommend doing it this way; it's a perfect use case for this function.

Comment: This is really useful, only thing is that it does not have a new line after each row ends. Maybe it was not clear in my question, but, I would like to have 5 separate rows of "1 2 3...n n n-1 n-2 ..1"

Comment: @Juanito My guess is that you are using Notepad from Windows to open the output files. Unlike everyone else Windows uses "\r\n" to delimit end of line instead of the usual "\n". To fix this, add `'newline', 'pc'` to the list of parameters passed to `dlmwrite`.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was using notepad to open the files. Your input works perfectly,  this is excellent!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a normal *.txt kind of file, I would normally use a for loop with fprintf(fileid,'%d things to print',5), with the appropriate fopen(.) statement. You'd be surprised what a good job fopen with 'w' and 'a' does. Try it and let us know!

In response to rayryeng: You are right! Here is a sample of code for writing a matrix to file using fprintf, without a for-loop.

```
A=rand(5);
fid=fopen('Rand_mat.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%0.4f %0.4f %0.4f %0.4f %0.4f\n',A');
fclose (fid);
```

where A is transposed because MATLAB reads the columns of the matrix first.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should illustrate your point with actual code.  Also, if you structure it carefully, you don't need a loop.  You can write entire matrices / arrays using a single call to `fprintf`.